# Spring Kafka Event after all listeners are started

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using Spring-Kakfa to connect kakfa cluster and I have a requirement to execute a piece of code after all the topic partitions of all the topics are assigned.
take the following code for example

```
     @Component
     public class MyKafkaMessageListener1 {
    
         @KafkaListener(topics = "topic1" , groupId = "cg1")
         public void handleMessage(String message){
               System.out.println("Msg:"+message);
         }
     }

     @Component
     public class MyKafkaMessageListener2 {
    
         @KafkaListener(topics = "topic2, topic3" , groupId = "cg2")
         public void handleMessage(String message){
               System.out.println("Msg:"+message);
         }
     }
```

I need to execute after all topic-partitions of topic1, topic2 and topic3 are assigned to threads. Is it possible? Is there such a EventHandler in kafka or spring-kafka?

Comment: You could inject a callback interface into both listener classes via a constructor/`@AutoWired` field that fires some event upon `handleMessage`, then track which listener/thread is being invoked, but this doesn't guarantee that `topic2,topic3` are both being consumed, only that you got _some message_ from one of them

Comment: I did not understand how the approach works, how a custom event from the handle method will solve this? I'm also looking for a way to notified after all partitions from all topics are assigned

Comment: Within `handleMessage`, you call a method of something else (an object that you'd need to pass to each listener class) to "notify it" that it was called (and therefore a thread has been activated). How you "track" which topic/thread is which, or if the threads get stopped, is a separate issue

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That won't work for my usecase, i want to get notified only once, after all partitions from all topics are assigned.

Comment: Sure, my suggestion is a two-step solution. You would need to track all the threads individually, and once you've collected messages from all of them, then send the event you really want

Answer (score 0):

Implement `ConsumerSeekAware` (or extend `AbstractConsumerSeekAware`), or add a `ConsumerRebalanceListener` and you will receive a call to `onPartitionsAssigned()`.

Comment: Gary, I tried that already but onPartitionsAssigned() is called every time a topic-partition is assigned to a thread, so if a topic had 20 partitions it's called 20 times and I have to know number of partitions the topic has and keep a count on how many times onPartitionsAssigned method is called and if the provider increase number of partitions my code will break. Also it will not work if there I have @KafkaListener annotations on different classes as shown in example right?

Comment: Yes it will work with multiple listeners, you just need to keep the state in a common class. You can use an `AdminClient` to get information about the topic(s) (number of partitions). `describeTopics()`.

Comment: Yes, this will work but the problem is we are using Azure Event Hubs with Kafka API and when we create SAS Key, it will only have option to read from topics, doesn't have permission to use AdminClient API with that SAS key :(